# Как в django_channels не потерять сообщения, если подключенного пользователя нет?

Tags: django, websocket, django-channels

я создал небольшой чат на django_channels, в чате должно быть 2 человека и если я отправляю сообщение в чат, то хочу, чтобы если в чате меньше 2 человек (илм если клиента нет), то помечтать его как не прочитанное при сохранении в базу, а при соединении запрашивать список всех не прочитанных и выдавать их.

Как это сделать? Не пойму как определить, что человек, которому я пишу не соединён с вебсокетом